# Passing multidimensional arrays to functions in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I'm currently reading a tutorial on C++ which states the following:

> When passing arrays of higher dimensions, only the first dimension can be open while the others must be known during compilation.

I need further explanation on this. When passing a 1D array (`int a[]`) to some function `f()` the arrays decays to a pointer `int* a`. I'm assuming that the above statement implies that a 2D array for example `int a[][]` decays to `int *a[]` or is it saying that only the first dimension can be dynamically allocated (which is nonsense). Specifically, what does "only the first dimension can be open" stating ? These are the only two explanations I was able to come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author is saying if a array is `int a[5][10]` and you want to pass that array to some function, then in function declaration you write the parameter accepting that array as `int x[][10]` and even that parameter i.e `int x[][10]` decays to `int (*x)[10]`

Anyways good way to pass 2D array is :

```
template<typename T, int first,int second>
void someFunction(T (&array)[first][second])
{....}
```

> I'm assuming that the above statement implies that a 2D array for
>   example int a[][] decays to int *a[]

`int a[x][y]` decays to `int (*a)[y]` i.e `a` is pointer to array of `y` ints, which is different from `int *a[y]` which means `a` is array of `y` int pointers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a two-dimensional array as for example

```
int a[M][N];
```

then used in expressions as for example like in an argument expression if the corresponding function parameter is not a reference it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element `int ( * )[N]`.

So for example you can write

```
int ( *p )[N] = a;
```

You can imagine it the following way.

If you have an array

```
T a[M};
```

then it is implicitly converted in expressions with rare exceptions to pointer to its first element `T *`.

If you have a two-dimensional array

```
int a[M][N];
```

you can represent it the following way

```
typedef int T[N];
T a[M];
```

So the pointer will look like

```
T *p = a;
```

where the type T is one-dimensional array `int [N]`